# Wordpress file upload issue : An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

Hi i am facing an issue during upload image into Media section of Wordpress. 
This is my screenshot : http://prntscr.com/hgjkle

I have tried all the basic steps to fix this issue but unfortunately I haven't had any success yet. The steps I have tried are: by .htaccess file by add code  into `Function.php`

```
add_filter('wp_image_editirs','change_graphic-lib');

function change_graphic_lib($array){
    return array('WP_Image_Editor_GD','WP_Image_Editor_Imagick');
}
```

I have also set the right permissions (755) to the upload folder, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that wp_post table was corrupted while update latest wordpress  verion. There is no Auto-increment ID under **wp_post**  due to this all newly upload files get 0 value in return.

Due to this "images" are not uploaded into the gallery.

** Steps to fix this issue**
1. Open your phpmyadmin 
2. open your website  data-base
3. open **posts table** and open structure of table. set ID as Primary Key From where  restoring AUTO INCREMENT on the posts table

After that you can reload media page now you can easily able to upload images in media....

that's it.

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: I have a multi-site version of WordPress and this post ended hours of looking.  In the case of multi-site you must modify the wp_xx_posts where xx is their site id.  Change the properties of the ID column so that it is AUTO_INCREMENT which will be default make it primary.  Immediately everything worked - media was made visible and uploads worked.

Most importantly, I have verified that other multi-site sites that were working normally already had ID set to AUTO_INCREMENT so that is what it should be!!

Answer (score 0):

Login into wordpress
Settings -> Media -> under Uploading Files check "Store uploads in this folder" check if wordpress upload folder path is mentioned there.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Siddhesh-damble File uploaded into correct folder which is based on current month... there is an something else,  along with file upload issue i am also not able to upload new Post :(

Comment: In that case there can be 2-3 things like Increase PHP memory, disable mod_security, check php.ini or .htaccess settings.

Hope you find the solution from this things.

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqlcheck -r DATABASE ...