# Wordpress error uploading media come back later

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have been searching many forum to resolve this problem and followed many possible resolution practice but I still see the same error when uploading media:error uploading media come back later
note that the image exist in the correct folder uploads, when I check using my FTP to connect to the server. And the image is visible using the URL
I tried the following but with no luck at all, and clear the cache each time on both my server and the browser:

- Deactivate all the plugin
- raise the php memory limit to 286M
- use a small image
- change the file permission to 755, I even tried 777
- use another theme
- I have the latest PHP version and the latest WordPress version
- it's not a limit from my server host
- made some change in the functions.php to change the image editor
  I just cannot find the problem
  here's the URL of the site if that can help: https://onzeonze.media

Comment: How heavy are the images? Some servers have quite a low limit on uploading files. Also, I have come across an issue where servers would limit execution on larger files since WordPress generates thumbnails and such when an image is uploaded. Clearway to see if it is a server issue is to set up a new WordPress install with one of the WordPress themes and see if that allowed files to be uploaded, if not, it is a server issue.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a server issue. I did try with a very small image, I did deactivate all the plugins and even try with another them, but nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest turning on the WP_DEBUG function so the error will give you more details, it sounds like it's uploading but not being recorded in the database, therefore wordpress won't see the image. There are plugin's to scan the uploads folder for images, but this isn't ideal.

To enable the debug and to show the issue add/edit in the wp-config.php

```
// Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

Here is more info: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Remember to turn that off when you're done with it, this can make your wp venerable!

Comment: I did enable the Debug and I got this error message in the debug.log:

Comment: I did enable the Debug and I got this error message in the debug.log:
`PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home2/annelang/public_html/onzeonze/wp-includes/post.php on line 7138`
on the post.php on line 7137 to 7139 I got this:
`foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  wp_cache_add( $post->ID, $post, 'posts' );
 }`
Does it sounds familiar to anyone?

Comment: There was on another error in the debug log 
`PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in /home2/annelang/public_html/onzeonze/wp-includes/post.php on line 7223`
and from the post.php from line 7219 to line 7224 I can see this code
`update_post_cache( $posts );

 $post_ids = array();
 foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  $post_ids[] = $post->ID;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check if your `wp_posts` table is corrupted using the steps mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66793243/16094181).

### Check Auto Increment

You can check the `wp_posts` table using phpMyAdmin. **Please ensure that you backup your database before making any changes.**

From phpMyAdmin, select your site's database and then click on the `wp_posts` table. Navigate to the **Structure** tab for the table. Check if the ID is set as the primary key and AUTO_INCREMENT is set for the ID as shown. If it is not, use the **Change** option to add the AUTO_INCREMENT in the Extra column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But do you know how to do it exactly?
I am not too familiar with PHPMyAdmin so I am not sure what I am doing. Can you explain more in detail the step 3: set ID as Primary Key From where restoring AUTO INCREMENT on the posts table How do you set Primary Key From restoring AUTO INCREMENT on post table? Thanks

Comment: @Lanaone - please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help and detailed explanation, I was missing those detail. From the beginning I have the feeling the problem come from PHPMyAdmin, but I am not too sure how to make change there. It looks like that database limits the access. I have other WordPress sites with database in the same location and where I have NO limitation on EDIT. But this one does! It doesn't save if I select Auto increment and it gives an error if I try to set it as primary key! The error is:
#1067-Invalid default value for post_date
Alter table 'wpry_post' Add primary key ('ID');